# How to create two choices fields by using foreign key from another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to create a model which will hold the routes between two places, but I don't know how to handle choices fields in this model, also my choices should hold only places (village, city, and town)

my Place model:

```py
class Place(CoreModel):
    TOWN = 'town'
    CITY = 'city'
    REGION = 'region'
    DISTRICT = 'district'
    VILLAGE = 'village'

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (REGION, 'область'),
        (CITY, 'місто'),
        (DISTRICT, 'район'),
        (TOWN, 'село міського типу'),
        (VILLAGE, 'село')
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Place name', )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

my Route model:

```py
class Routes(CoreModel): 
    start_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    end_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What does `does not work` mean?

Comment: @Ivan Starostin it means that I got an error while try to migrate

Comment: add the details of your issue to the question: what command you're running and what's the error (full error trace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a model with two `ForeignKey`s to the same model, you must give at least one of them a `related_name` otherwise django doesn't know how to differentiate them in the reverse relationship:

```
class Routes(CoreModel):
    start_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="departing_routes")
    end_point = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="arriving_routes")
```